# Merging lists with a for loop

Tags: c#, list, merge

I'm working on an algorithm which can generate 2 types of recommendations, restaurants and dishes. All of this works fine, but I wanted to merge these 2 types of recommendations in a single list, which is where I encountered some issues. From [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124085/filling-list-with-different-types-of-objects) I concluded that I needed a wrapper class, which I have set up like this:

```
public class RecommenderItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public object Entity { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to alternate the 2 types of recommendations so the list would look like this:

```
[Restaurant][Dish][Restaurant][Dish][Restaurant][Dish] //Etc...
```

Note that these recommendations are completely separate. They are generated purely based on the user's preference, and they have no correlation in between them. My product owner wants to show these recommendations on the home page of our app like this.

These lists are different in length, so if I have added all items from a list, I wanted to just add the remaining objects from the other list. A possible scenario of this could look like this:

```
/*Other objects before this...*/[Dish][Restaurant][Dish][Dish][Dish] //Etc...
```

Here did the list of restaurant objects run out and I just wanted to add the remaining dish recommendations at the end of the list.

I have gotten this far, but I'm unsure how I would catch an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception and add the rest of the remaining objects at the end.

```
public List<RecommenderItem> GetMergedRecommendationLists(List<Restaurant> restaurantRecommendations, 
                                                           List<Dish> dishRecommendations)
    {
        //Setting up the output list.
        List<RecommenderItem> output = new List<RecommenderItem>();
        int count = 0;
        //Check which list is longer and use that count
        if (restaurantRecommendations.Count > dishRecommendations.Count)
            count = dishRecommendations.Count;
        else
            count = restaurantRecommendations.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            //I'm fully aware this isn't the most optimal way of doing this,
            //but I'm only looking at functionality here, optimizing performance comes later.
            var restRecommendation = restaurantRecommendations[i];
            var dishRecommendation = dishRecommendations[i];
            output.Add(new RecommenderItem()
            {
                Id = restRecommendation.Id,
                Entity = restRecommendation
            });
            output.Add(new RecommenderItem()
            {
                Id = dishRecommendation.Id,
                Entity = dishRecommendation
            });
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could do this? Could I just catch an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception and use `.AddRange()` for the remaining objects? I'm not sure how I could check which list was out of bounds.

Let me know if I should elaborate more and thanks in advance!

**Edit:** -removed because it wasn't fair.-

Comment: Did you check the [Enumerable.Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen My knowledge in C# is fairly limited, how would I use that in my scenario?

Comment: Instead of `object Entity` i would have a `Restaurant` class and a `Dish` class, a resurant has a `List<Dish>` as property. If you now want to recommend a dish for every restaurant that means you want to fill a `List<Restaurant>` where the `List<Dish>` is filled with one dish.

Comment: @TimSchmelter my product owner wants it this way though. These restaurants and dishes are completely separate and have no correlation in between them. I'll add that description to the question.

Comment: Note that your timings would need to be done for a release build to mean anything. Also you seem to have changed your requirements substantially, since the accepted answer doesn't create objects of a new type `RecommenderItem` as per your requirement... Thus the timings are even more meaningless since some answers create a new object, while others don't.

Comment: @MatthewWatson they still reflect the time it takes for each method, right? If I'm incorrect, please tell me and I'll change the accepted answer. Also, I changed it and used the implicit operators from m.rogalski. And since almost each answer does what I wanted to achieve, what would be the best way to accept the 'best' answer? Feel free to correct me and I'll change the accepted answer.

Comment: To be fair: 1) I'm not sure your benchmark is correct (release build, with no debugger and jitting code previously) 2) Mathew's code creates instances of `RecommenderItem` while mine doesn't. The solutions are basically the same so there can't be that much difference (~30%). I've put together a small test and mine is marginally faster (2%) but in any case, both are blinding fast and I really doubt performance has any bearing whatsoever in what implementation you should choose.

Comment: Well if your requirement is simply to interleave the elements of two sequences of the same type, you should put that as your requirement, and then the accepted answer would match your requirement - but as it is, the accepted answer does not match your stated requirement.

Comment: You both made fair points, but I'm still confused how I would choose between answers which all match my requirements. I'm sorry if I'm being confusing, I do want to accept the 'best' answer.

Comment: The fundamentally important answer is probably from @m.rogalski, since that is the one that has allowed a much simpler solution to work.

Comment: You are correct. I would like to apologize for the confusion I caused! Changed the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My recommendation would be to just make simple [implicit operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) :

```
public static implicit operator RecommenderItem(Restaurant restaurant) {
    return new RecommenderItem { Id = restaurant.Id, Entity = restaurant };
}
```

Then you have possibility to convert these types easily like :

```
Restaurant rest = //...
RecommenderItem rItem = rest; // here the implicit operator is called
```

After doing this you can just use one for loop :

```
int count = Math.Max(restaurantRecommendations.Count, dishRecommendations.Count);
for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
    if ( i < restRecommendations.Count )
        output.Add(restRecommendations[i]);

    if ( i < dishRecommendations.Count )
        output.Add(dishRecommendations[i]);
}
```

This will make your work much more easier.

Comment: Well, you need also one from `Dish` to `RecommenderItem`. Personally i don't like such magic conversions because they are hidden to all who aren't so familiar with the classes. But nice idea anyway.

Comment: Well.. i thought that was obvious. Same like you should make opposite operators ( from `RecommenderItem` to `Restaurant` )

Comment: Only do this is both clases are in the same domain, otherwise you'll need a reference to the other assembly in order to compile the first.

Answer (score 15):

This is a fairly succinct way of doing this.

While not Linq, it works in the spirit of the way Linq works by deferring doing any work until the resulting sequence is enumerated:

```
public static IEnumerable<RecommenderItem> Merge(IEnumerable<Restaurant> restaurants, IEnumerable<Dish> dishes)
{
    using (var r = restaurants.GetEnumerator())
    using (var d = dishes.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            bool rAvailable = r.MoveNext();
            bool dAvailable = d.MoveNext();

            if (rAvailable)
                yield return new RecommenderItem { Id = r.Current.Id, Entity = r.Current };

            if (dAvailable)
                yield return new RecommenderItem { Id = d.Current.Id, Entity = d.Current };

            if (!rAvailable && !dAvailable)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you happen to be using the `MoreLinq` NuGet package that includes [the `ZipLongest` extension method](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.ZipLongest/1.0.1), you can use the following simplified implementation instead:

```
public static IEnumerable<RecommenderItem> Merge(IEnumerable<Restaurant> restaurants, IEnumerable<Dish> dishes)
{
    foreach (var item in restaurants.ZipLongest(dishes, (r, d) => new { r, d }))
    {
        if (item.r != null)
            yield return new RecommenderItem { Id = item.r.Id, Entity = item.r };

        if (item.d != null)
            yield return new RecommenderItem { Id = item.d.Id, Entity = item.d };
    }
}
```

---

**Addendum**

As @InBetween posted in his answer, you can put the interleaving logic into an extension method. Here's my version; it's substantially the same, except I've added a small optimisation to avoid calling `.MoveNext()` when its not necessary:

```
public static class EnumerableExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Interleave<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
    {
        using (var ae = a.GetEnumerator())
        using (var be = b.GetEnumerator())
        {
            bool aAvailable = true;
            bool bAvailable = true;

            while (aAvailable || bAvailable)
            {
                aAvailable = aAvailable && ae.MoveNext();
                bAvailable = bAvailable && be.MoveNext();

                if (aAvailable)
                    yield return ae.Current;

                if (bAvailable)
                    yield return be.Current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have that, I realised that you don't need to write an `implict` operator. Instead, you can just convert the two sequences to the resultant type before calling `Interleave()` like so:

```
var restaurantsAsRecommenderItems = 
    restaurantRecommendations
    .Select(r => new RecommenderItem {Id = r.Id, Entity = r});

var dishesAsRecommenderItems = 
    dishRecommendations
    .Select(d => new RecommenderItem {Id = d.Id, Entity = d});

var result =
    restaurantsAsRecommenderItems
    .Interleave(dishesAsRecommenderItems)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I have just tested this, but it doesn't add the remaining objects once one of the two lists is empty.

Comment: @Bas Ah, I misunderstood your requirement, which says `i just wanted to dump the rest of the dish recommendations at the end of the list.`. I took `dump` to mean `discard` but you really mean `concatenate` I assume.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I meant it that you need to dump the remaining objects at the end of the list. I'll word it differently.

Comment: This is my favourite, uses deferred execution and is still efficient and readable

Answer (score 6):

Well, there are probably more elegant LINQ solutions but you have already most, it's also a very efficient approach:

```
public List<RecommenderItem> GetMergedRecommendationLists(List<Restaurant> restaurantRecommendations, List<Dish> dishRecommendations)
{
    //Setting up the output list.
    List<RecommenderItem> output = new List<RecommenderItem>();
    int count = Math.Min(restaurantRecommendations.Count, dishRecommendations.Count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var restRecommendation = restaurantRecommendations[i];
        var dishRecommendation = dishRecommendations[i];
        output.Add(new RecommenderItem()
        {
            Id = restRecommendation.Id,
            Entity = restRecommendation
        });
        output.Add(new RecommenderItem()
        {
            Id = dishRecommendation.Id,
            Entity = dishRecommendation
        });
    }
    int remainingRestaurant = restaurantRecommendations.Count - count;
    int remainingDishes = dishRecommendations.Count - count;
    if (remainingRestaurant > 0)
    {
        for (int i = count; i < restaurantRecommendations.Count; i++)
        {
            var restRecommendation = restaurantRecommendations[i];
            output.Add(new RecommenderItem()
            {
                Id = restRecommendation.Id,
                Entity = restRecommendation
            });
        }
    }
    else if (remainingDishes > 0)
    {
        for (int i = count; i < dishRecommendations.Count; i++)
        {
            var dishRecommendation = dishRecommendations[i];
            output.Add(new RecommenderItem()
            {
                Id = dishRecommendation.Id,
                Entity = dishRecommendation
            });
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Would this be more efficient than using LINQ or any of the above answers? I'll benchmark them all, it would just save me some time ^^

Comment: @Bas: this is the most efficient approach because it is based on simple math and a for-loop that uses the list indexer. But performance is not most important. Use code that you (and your colleagues) understand, so that you can find bugs or maintain it. Loop based approaches have another advantage: thery are easy to debug and you can add logging and error handling easily. Btw, i'm a great LINQ fan ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't this output duplicates (starting from 0) instead of the remaining items?

Comment: No, still not right. You want `i` to go from `count` to `restaurantRecommendations.Count - 1` and `dishRecommendations.Count - 1`.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou: that's the reason why i like Mathew's answer. No indexes or claculation needed

Comment: I meant the for-loop condition should be `i < restaurantRecommendations.Count` which would make it go up to (and including) `restaurantRecommendations.Count - 1`.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way of doing it would be:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
{
    using (var firstEnumerator = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (var secondEnumerator = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (firstEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
           yield return firstEnumerator.Current;

            if (secondEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return secondEnumerator.Current;
            }
        }

        while (secondEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return secondEnumerator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well and does what it's supposed to, but I needed to concentrate in order to understand it, because the source code is not "symmetric" between first and second argument.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Very true. The answer was more intended in showing a simple algorithm the merges both lists as required. Mathew's answer, which is essentially the same as mine, addreses the type assymetry.

Answer (score 2):

After having created two arrays of restaurants and dishes of the same type `RecommenderItem`, you can use the Zip method like :

```
var restaurants = restaurantRecommendations.Select(x => new RecommenderItem {
                                                        Id = x.Id,
                                                        Entity = x 
                                                     }).ToArray();
var dishes = dishRecommendations.Select(x => new RecommenderItem {
                                                        Id = x.Id,
                                                        Entity = x 
                                                     }).ToArray();
var output = restaurants.Zip(dishes, (r, d) => new[] { r, d })
              .SelectMany(r => r).Concat(dishes.Skip(restaurants.Length))
              .Concat(restaurants.Skip(dishes.Length));
```

Answer (score 0):

Restaraunt and Dish would have to share a base type:

```
restaurantRecommendations.Select(item => new RecommenderItem()
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Entity = item
        });
dishRecommendations.Select(item => new RecommenderItem()
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Entity = item
        });
```

Once that's the case you could use something like this slightly modified version of `Zip` (from `System.Linq`):

```
    private static IEnumerable<T> ZipThrough<T>(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
    {
        if (first == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(first));
        if (second == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(second));
        using (var e1 = first.GetEnumerator())
        {
            using (var e2 = second.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (true)
                    if (e1.MoveNext())
                    {
                        yield return e1.Current;

                        if (e2.MoveNext()) yield return e2.Current;
                    }
                    else if (e2.MoveNext())
                    {
                        yield return e2.Current;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```